# How do i persist this change of layout in database using JQuery Portlet?

Tags: jquery

I just saw this cool feature of JQuery which is JQuery Portlet

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/portlets.html

I was just wondering how do i persist this to my database? so that it's available even for future sessions to all users of my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's Portlet widget has a `serialize` method that would do just that. Read how to use it here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize

> Serializes the sortable's item id's into a form/ajax submittable string. Calling this method produces a hash that can be appended to any url to easily submit a new item order back to the server.
>
> It works by default by looking at the id of each item in the format 'setname_number', and it spits out a hash like "setname[]=number&setname[]=number".
>
> You can also give in a option hash as second argument to custom define how the function works. The possible options are: 'key' (replaces part1[] with whatever you want), 'attribute' (test another attribute than 'id') and 'expression' (use your own regexp).
>
> If serialize returns an empty string, make sure the id attributes include an underscore. They must be in the form: "set_number" For example, a 3 element list with id attributes foo_1, foo_5, foo_2 will serialize to foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2. You can use an underscore, equal sign or hyphen to separate the set and number. For example foo=1 or foo-1 or foo_1 all serialize to foo[]=1.